# How to get code from Bitbucket via Octopus?

Tags: automation, bitbucket, octopus-deploy

Is there a way that I can tell Octopus to take its code from Bitbucket and not GitHub (without using Bitbucket's pipelines)? I couldn't anything under community steps that would let me do that (somewhat surprisingly).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Octopus supports a push from BitBucket, but not a pull (https://octopus.com/blog/bitbucket-pipes-and-octopus-deploy)

Github supports either option: https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-repositories/github-feeds